# Why does the function run twice in my every component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this problem where i made three different components with routing. The problem is when i open my different components they loop twice at the moment i open them. What is causing this and how can i get rid of it?

**Heres one example component which `console.log` runs twice when i open it.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';   
import nameData from '../../names/names.json'
    
interface INames {
        name: string,
        amount: number
}

const { names } = nameData

@Component({
    selector: 'app-four',
    templateUrl: './four.html',
    styleUrls: ["./four.css"]
})


export class FourComponent {

    nameArray: Array<INames> = names

    constructor() { 
        
    }

    hasName(nameParam: any) {
        console.log("miksi tämä tulee kaksi kertaa")
        
        return this.nameArray.some(elem => elem.name === nameParam)
    }
}
```

**And here is the app.module.ts and app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OneComponent } from './requirements/one/one';
import { TwoComponent } from './requirements/two/two';
import { ThreeComponent } from './requirements/three/three';
import { FourComponent } from './requirements/four/four';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OneComponent,
    TwoComponent,
    ThreeComponent,
    FourComponent,
    HeaderComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home';
import { FourComponent } from './requirements/four/four';
import { OneComponent } from './requirements/one/one';
import { ThreeComponent } from './requirements/three/three';
import { TwoComponent } from './requirements/two/two';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent },
  { path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent },
  { path: 'four', component: FourComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm really confused why it loops the function as soon as i press the components button?

[image]

Comment: Where are you using the hasName() function.
Could you share it please.

Comment: If you are using `hasName` in template it's because it renders multiple time. Such operation should be called carefully, only when necessary - when you change input value.

Answer (score -1):

I do not recommand at all to use function in the HTML template, because they will be called everytime the Angular's change detection runs. Angular isn't able to tell if the result of the function will be different after each modification, si Angular will call the function everytime something change in the UI.

You must store the result of the function in a variable. Angular can check that the reference of the variable hasn't change.

You can read more information about it on [this medium](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496).

I recommend that you do the following

```js
public fullName: string;

constructor() { 
    this.updateName();      
}

private updateName(nameParam: any) {
    console.log("miksi tämä tulee kaksi kertaa");
        
    this.fullName = this.nameArray.some(elem => elem.name === nameParam);
}
```

```html
{{ fullName }}
```